# Handling FileNotFound Exception

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008

```
cn.Open()
    Dim query As String
    query = "INSERT INTO Documents(AdmissionNumber,FullName,LeavingCertificate,KCPEResultSlip,BirthCertificate,MedicalCertificate,ParentOrGuardianPhoto,ParentGuardianIDFront,ParentGuardianIDBack,AnyOtherDocument) VALUES('" & Tbx1.Text & "','" & Tbx2.Text & "', @LeavingCertificate,@KCPEResultSlip,@BirthCertificate,@MedicalCertificate,@ParentOrGuardianPhoto,@ParentGuardianIDFront,@ParentGuardianIDBack,@AnyOtherDocument)"
    cmd = New SqlCommand(query, cn)
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlClient.SqlParameter("@LeavingCertificate", SqlDbType.Image)).Value = IO.File.ReadAllBytes(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlClient.SqlParameter("@KCPEResultSlip", SqlDbType.Image)).Value = IO.File.ReadAllBytes(OpenFileDialog2.FileName)
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlClient.SqlParameter("@BirthCertificate", SqlDbType.Image)).Value = IO.File.ReadAllBytes(OpenFileDialog3.FileName)
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlClient.SqlParameter("@MedicalCertificate", SqlDbType.Image)).Value = IO.File.ReadAllBytes(OpenFileDialog4.FileName)
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlClient.SqlParameter("@ParentOrGuardianPhoto", SqlDbType.Image)).Value = IO.File.ReadAllBytes(OpenFileDialog5.FileName)
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlClient.SqlParameter("@ParentGuardianIDFront", SqlDbType.Image)).Value = IO.File.ReadAllBytes(OpenFileDialog6.FileName)
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlClient.SqlParameter("@ParentGuardianIDBack", SqlDbType.Image)).Value = IO.File.ReadAllBytes(OpenFileDialog7.FileName)
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlClient.SqlParameter("@AnyOtherDocument", SqlDbType.Image)).Value = IO.File.ReadAllBytes(OpenFileDialog8.FileName)

    Reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
    MsgBox("Students' Documents Added Successfully to The Regista.", MsgBoxStyle.Information + MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly)
    Btn9_Click(sender, e)


End Sub
```

' Hi comrades. You see this code above? This item called (AnyOtherDocument) is optional. The user can either provide it or Not. But when not provided, am getting an Exception error. How do I handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check with File.Exists. If there is no file then set the parameter to DbNull.Value otherwise read the file

```
Dim exists = File.Exists(OpenFileDialog8.FileName)

.....
cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlClient.SqlParameter( _ 
     "@AnyOtherDocument", SqlDbType.Image)).Value _
     = If(exists, IO.File.ReadAllBytes(OpenFileDialog8.FileName), _
                  DBNull.Value)
```

By the way, you are using parameters for all of your image values, why don't you use them also for the two string values? The usefulness of parameters is not tied to the DataType of the value to pass. You use them for every value to avoid [Sql Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work) and parsing problems

```
query = "INSERT INTO Documents " & _
"(AdmissionNumber,FullName,LeavingCertificate,KCPEResultSlip," & _ 
"BirthCertificate,MedicalCertificate,ParentOrGuardianPhoto," & _
"ParentGuardianIDFront,ParentGuardianIDBack,AnyOtherDocument) " & _
"VALUES(@admnum, @fullname,  @LeavingCertificate,@KCPEResultSlip, " & _
"@BirthCertificate,@MedicalCertificate,@ParentOrGuardianPhoto," & _
"@ParentGuardianIDFront,@ParentGuardianIDBack,@AnyOtherDocument)"

cmd = New SqlCommand(query, cn)
cmd.Parameters.Add("@admnum", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Tbx1.Text 
cmd.Parameters.Add("@fullname", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Tbx2.Text 
cmd.Parameters.Add("@LeavingCertificate", SqlDbType.Image).Value = IO.File.ReadAllBytes(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
.... and so on with all the other parameters ....
```

Comment: Steve am so new in this. How I wish you can rewrite that code the way u are putting it and post it here i review.

Comment: I have just added a line to check if the file exists befor opening the connection, then I have changed the line that creates the @AnyOtherDocument parameter. What is not clear here?

Comment: This one is okay in fact it has worked just so perfectly. Am saying you have told me that am using parameters for all my image values. Is there any better way i can do this?

Comment: I wish you use parameters for everything. You have two values  (strings) that you don't pass as parameters. You should.

Comment: Now i get you. I'll definitely do that now.